# Extract words between begin and end, \G \K

Tags: regex, perl

This pattern does the work

```
(?:\G(?!\A)|begin).*?\K(keyword)(?=.*end)
```

String:

```
begin
keyword
keyword 
end
```

I get what I  want (keyword keyword) in just one capture group, but if the string has this:

```
begin
keyword
keyword 
end
keyword
end
```

I get three matches, How to stop in the first `end` ?

Can be this pattern be better, optimized?

[demo regex](https://regex101.com/r/Xw1ueP/2)

Comment: `(?:\G(?!\A)|begin)(?:(?!begin|end).)*?\K(keyword)(?=.*end)` or `(?:\G(?!\A)|begin)(?:(?!begin|end).)*?\K(keyword)(?=(?:(?!begin).)*end)`

Comment: Why dont't you just match `begin` and `end` too and then extract a matching group? Would simplify the pattern..

Comment: TRY:  SEARCH: `(?s).*?(begin)(?-s).*\R((?:.*\R)*?).*(end)(?s).*`  REPLACE BY:`\1\r\2\3`

see here:  https://regex101.com/r/Xw1ueP/3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would hate to run across such a regex in code. Any small change and it's broken.

I'd open a filehandle on a reference to the string then read its lines. Skip everything until you run into the starting line, then read everything up to the ending line:

```
use v5.26;

my $string =<<~'HERE';
    begin
    keyworda
    keywordb
    end
    keywordc
    end
    HERE

open my $fh, '<', \$string;

while( <$fh> ) { last if /\Abegin/ }

my @keywords;
while( <$fh> ) {
    last if /^end/;
    chomp;
    push @keywords, $_;
    }

say join "\n", @keywords;
```

This outputs:

```
keyworda
keywordb
```

Or, break it up into two regexes. One sets the starting position, then you repeatedly match as long as the line isn't the ending line. This is a bit cleaner, but some people may be confused by the global matching in scalar context:

```
use v5.26;

my $string =<<~'HERE';
    begin
    keyworda
    keywordb
    end
    keywordc
    end
    HERE

my @keywords;
if( $string =~ / ^ begin \R /gmx ) {
    while( $string =~ /\G (?!end \R) (\N+) \R /gx ) {
        push @keywords, $1;
        }
    }

say join "\n", @keywords;
```

Answer (score -1):

Use regular expression and store match in an array

```
my @result = $data =~ /begin\n(.*?)\nend/sg;
```

then output to console

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use Data::Dumper;

my $data = do { local $/; <DATA> };

my @result = $data =~ /begin\n(.*?)\nend/sg;

say '-' x 35 . "\n" . $_ for @result;

__DATA__
begin
keyword 1
keyword 2
end
keyword
end
keyword
begin
keyword 3
keyword 4
end
keyword 
keyword
```

Output

```
-----------------------------------
keyword 1
keyword 2
-----------------------------------
keyword 3
keyword 4
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `not equal` in grouping to fetch the data from `begin` to `end`.

```
 my @keyws = ($data=~/begin((?:(?!begin|end).)*)end/sg);

 use Data::Dumper;

 print Dumper @keyws;
```

It's my way to doing in LaTeX.